# How to make my functions produce different results when called multiple times?

Tags: function, processing

I'm using the sketch language Processing to create try and create an image. For the most part, I have my code down and functional, but I've run into a problem with my function fade(), which is intended to create a fade in and fade out effect for the shapes I've drawn. My problem is that I call this function multiple times (for each rectangle I have drawn), and I want the effects of this function to be unique for each rectangle. I used randomness within the function fade() to try and implement this but to no avail. When I run the program, all of the rectangles I have drawn fade in and out together instead of individually.

I've attached my code below to provide a better sense of the issue I am having. I feel like there is a simple solution in the methodology of my code, but I can't quite place it. Please let me know if you have any suggestions or areas in which you think I should alter.

```
int f = 0;
boolean fadingIn = true;
int time = millis();
float randomHold;
float randomFade;

void setup(){
  size(600, 560);
  rectMode(CENTER);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(3);
  
  randomHold = random(3, 8);
  randomFade = random(0, 2);
  
  // Bottom Right Corner
  stroke(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255), fade());
  rect(540, 500, 100, 100, 10);
  
  // Right Side (bottom first)
  stroke(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255), fade());
  rect(540, 390, 100, 100, 10);
  stroke(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255), fade());
  rect(540, 280, 100, 100, 10);
  stroke(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255), fade());
  rect(540, 170, 100, 100, 10);
  stroke(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255), fade());
  rect(540, 60, 100, 100, 10);
}

int fade(){
  
  if (f >= 255){
    if ((millis() - time) >= (1000*randomHold))
    {
      fadingIn = false;
      time = millis();
      randomHold = random(3, 8);
    }
  } else if (f <= 0){
    if ((millis() - time) >= (1000*randomHold))
    {
      fadingIn = true;
      time = millis();
      randomHold = random(3, 8);
    }
  }
  
  if (fadingIn){
    f += (int)randomFade;
    randomFade = random(0, 2);
  }
  
  if (!fadingIn){
    f -= (int)randomFade;
    randomFade = random(0, 2);
  }
  
  return f;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In mathematics, you might recall that something is called a "function" when it passes the "vertical line test". What that means is that it has exactly one output for a certain input, which means that if you pass the same input parameters into a function every time, it will give the same output every time. At least, that's how it works in mathematics.

"Functions" in the computer science sense *can* give different outputs for the same input (and there is often no input at all). One example is the `random(low, high)` function. How does `random(low, high)` return different values? Well it might look like there are only two inputs, but in the math sense of what a "function" is, `random(low, high)` has a *third* input: the seed. If you run the following code:

```
void draw() {
  randomSeed(23410832);
  println(random(0, 255));
}
```

you will see that if you set the seed to the same value every time, `random(low, high)` will yield the same output every time.

You seem to have a grasp of this, because you use "bonus" inputs `f`, `time`, `randomHold`, and `fadingIn`, and you change each of them every single time the function is run*. Here's the problem: you don't change them *enough*.

*(you also have the bonus variable `randomFade`, but the `fade()` function doesn't directly affect that one)

If you run your code similarly to the `draw()` loop above:

```
void draw() {
  println(fade());
}
```

you'll notice that the output doesn't change very much from one call to the next. It gradually goes up to 255, then back down to 0, then back up, and so on. What you're looking for is something that changes gradually on every fifth call, but changes drastically from one to the next, somewhat like this:

- `fade()` outputs 1
- `fade()` outputs 150
- `fade()` outputs 68
- `fade()` outputs 233
- `fade()` outputs 100
- `fade()` outputs 2
- `fade()` outputs 149
- `fade()` outputs 67
- `fade()` outputs 234
- `fade()` outputs 99

The way to do this is by giving `fade()` an input, and calling it with five distinct inputs over and over again:

- `fade(1)` outputs 1
- `fade(2)` outputs 150
- `fade(3)` outputs 68
- `fade(4)` outputs 233
- `fade(5)` outputs 100
- `fade(1)` outputs 2
- `fade(2)` outputs 149
- `fade(3)` outputs 67
- `fade(4)` outputs 234
- `fade(5)` outputs 99

Here is my solution:

```
float t = 0;
float[] inps = new float[5];

void setup(){
  size(600, 560);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  colorMode(HSB);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    inps[i] = random(TWO_PI);
  }
  noFill();
  strokeWeight(3);
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    stroke(random(255), 255, fade(inps[i]));
    rect(540, 500 - 110 * i, 100, 100, 10);
  }
  t = (t + 0.01)%TWO_PI;
}

float fade(float offset){
  return map(sin(t + offset), -1, 1, 0, 255);
}
```

There might be a fair amount of stuff in there that you're not familiar with, but here's basically what I did:

- make a variable `t` which will change continuously (we can get an oscillating value for the brightness of the rectangles through `sin(t)`).
- make a list `inps` (it's technically an array, not a list, but the distinction isn't important here) of 5 random inputs for the new `fade()` function.
- use the color mode HSB (hue, saturation, brightness)
- associate each rectangle with one of those inputs (this is the `for` loop inside of `draw()`
- for each rectangle, calculate the `fade()` of its associated input, which will be `sin(t + offset)`, except it's stretched out from 0 to 255 instead of being just -1 to 1.
- for the color of the rectangle, pick a random hue, give it full saturation (255), and use the `fade()` value for the brightness.

There are some drawbacks to this, but they can usually be overcome. Let me know if you're having trouble with something more specific.

Comment: Thank you so much! You provided a lot of useful information that I don't 100% understand  yet, but you laid everything out for me, which I appreciate so much. I'm going to take some time to break down your suggestions and code and will reach out again if I have any specific questions or matters that I'd like some clarification with. Again, thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome! If you want good explanations of some of these concepts, I highly recommend The Coding Train on Youtube.